# Why are the stacktraces missing when I log node errors?

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I log errors in node.js v4, they are often missing the stacktrace, which is replaced by `Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`.   For example:

```
   Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at <error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined>
    at <error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined>
    at <error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined>
    at <error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined>
    at <error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined>
    at <error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined>
    at <error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined>
    at <error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined>
    at <error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined>
    at <error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined>
```

Note the stacktrace lines.  It seems that the stacktrace is inaccesible somehow, and unavailable in the error object.

Does anyone know why this might happen?

Here's another example:

Comment: Can you add minimal code to reproduce the problem, maybe calling the function recursively infinitely

Comment: sounds like a recursive function or property.

Comment: Right, the error itself is just an example.  But what's wrong with the stacktrace?